# How is the cost of landing on a property with x houses determined?

Tags: monopoly

I’m trying to make a digital version of Monopoly, and it would be easiest for me if I could use the base rent of a property to determine the rent with any number of houses. Is there a formula/equation that can be used to do so?

Comment: If you have a game available, it is easy to figure this out yourself.

Comment: Unless one is quite a capable mathematician, finding the equations that would give the correct rent for 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 houses is not *"easy to figure out"* at all. Perhaps Trevor is asking precisely because of that. @ToonKrijthe

Answer (score 4):

There is no formula that the game uses, different properties go up at different rates, and not always a consistent rate. You'll need to hard code the per property rent values into your system unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.falstad.com/monopoly.html) are the Rents for all of the Monopoly properties that can be developed, with their names in both the traditional Atlantic City version as well as the London England version:

[image: Monopoly Rents]